# Tor browser stuck at 'loading network status'

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

It was working fine, I checked for update and updated and it auto restarted . Since then it is stuck at that point. Tried exiting and restarting but no result.

**EDIT:** to clarify my problem, after I booted to windows 10, I opened Tor browser first. It opened as usual . I saw a notification to check for update and I clicked it so it downloaded latest version and updated and asked to restart tor browser. After clicking restart, It got stuck at where tor searches and connects to the tor network. precisely at where it shows 'loading network status' in that small window.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. It was due to my time setting. Due to Dual boot, When I booted to windows it was some different time. In my defense, it should not have worked first time I opened it rather It gave error after I updated it.